# Simplifying and finding PDF: $ \frac{\arcsin{(x \sin{\theta})} - \theta}{\sin{\theta}} $

Tags: probability, trigonometry

\begin{align*}
D = \frac{\arcsin{(X \sin{\theta})} - \theta}{\sin{\theta}}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
X \sim \text{Uniform}[-1, 1], \hspace{0.5in} \theta \sim \text{Uniform}[0, 2 \pi]
\end{align*}

How to find the PDF of $D$? or is there anyway to simplify the equation of $D$!?

Comment: Isn't it that for $\theta<\pi$, $d$ becomes negative?

Comment: Sorry .. forget about the P(d > 0) .. what about calculating the PDF??

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Fabian's comment, for $\theta < \pi$, $d \ge 0$ iff $\arcsin(x \sin \theta) \ge \theta$ iff $x \sin \theta \ge \sin \theta$, that is, never for $x \le 1$.

And for $\pi < \theta < 2\pi$, $d \ge 0$ iff $\arcsin(x \sin \theta) \le \theta$ which is always true. Your probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks but I care more about calculating the PDF!!